# Check for screen using crontab

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, crontab

Currently, I'm using Debian with the following cronjob for screen at reboot:

```
@reboot screen -dmS app1 /home/app1
@reboot screen -dmS app2 /home/app2
```

The problem is, that sometimes the application doesn't run and the screen session gets terminated.
Is there any way for screen to check is this session working and if not to run it again, using cron on every 10 minutes (or something like that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a script along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP=$1
NAME=$2
screen -ls 2>&1 | grep ".$NAME" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    screen -dmS $NAME $APP
fi
```

Used like this - `<script-name> app1 /home/app1`

It'll look for running screen session with given name (for executing user) and if it doesn't find such - it'll spawn a new one.